# Create a view with three columns of three different tables using postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have three tables in my database t1, t2 and t2 with similar fields like this:
I have to create a materialized view in postgres with three columns, with all data that I have in the three tables.

In this case `t1.serial, t2.id, t3.serialno`, should be first column called `serial` in the view; `T1.type, t2.model, t3.typeof` should be the second column called `type` in the view and `t1.kind, t2.product and t3.ci_product` should be third column called `kind` in the view. I tried with joins but is not working. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

```
t1
------------------------
serial  type   kind
------------------------
qdds    cisco  switch
sjkal   ibm    router
dsafs   cisco  switch
```

t2:

```
t2
-----------------------
id      model  product
-----------------------
1223    ibm    switch
dsfsf22 ibm    switch
onakj   other  chassis
```

and t3:

```
t3
-----------------------
serialno typeof  ci_product
-----------------------
sdfs     ibm     switch
sdfsssa  twitter other
231dsfs  other   other
```

Comment: I think you need to tell us how these tables are related.  We should have to be left guessing about your data model.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this tables are not related, just serial, id, serialno means the same like type, model and typof and like kind, product and ci_product.

Comment: If you want a single view from these three tables, then you have to tell us how to connect them.   Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the three tables are not connected. Just I want all the tables records in a same table/view (all records are different) under the same name column. I don't know it's possible. I am little bit new with sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you mean UNION operator:

```
create materialized view as 
select t1.serial serial, t1.type type, t1.kind kind from t1
union
select t2.id, t2.model, t2.product from t2
union
select t3.serialno, t3.typeof, t3.ci_product from t3;
```

Comment: You probably want `UNION ALL` here.